# Table Opacity not rendered properly in IE?

Tags: html, css, opacity

I have a table http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOBVYp
this uses opacity to show a greyed out version of a table cell

but in IE 11 the output goes bad . The same works fine in a Chrome.. The table uses a javascript method to add certain styles applied to table cells input type radio/checkbox when checked on it.

Any thing in particular i need to add to make it work for IE . 
[image]

Still the same below is with the version of IE

[image]

Comment: Works pretty well for me in IE 11.0.9600.17691

Comment: Ditto, works for me in IE11 (11.0.9600.17728)

Comment: What version of IE? It should work from IE9 and up http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-opacity

Comment: Updated with version

Comment: I tried the same on a windows 8.1 machine with the exact same version of IE that is 11.0.9600.17728 the output rendered is fine in that machine. I use a WIndows 7 machine !

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in my IE 11 browser. you can try rgba background-color rather than opacity.

Comment: I use a windows 7 machine with IE 11 on it . Does not work for me !! Tried the same on a Windows 8.1 with same version works

Comment: CSS opacity works till IE7. So there may be some issue in your browser.. clear your cache properly. if It still doesn't work try to re-install your browser..